# How to auto-refresh Chrome in kiosk mode

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, kiosk

I've a computer (windows 10) with a link in the startup directory to launch a web page with Chrome in kiosk mode.
It opens correctly but displays a blank page, until I press F5, at which point the page loads correctly.

If I click on the shortcut when the PC is already booted, the page opens and loads correctly. The problem only occurs during automatic start-up.

If I remove the kiosk mode: Chrome opens with the address entered in the bar, but without loading it. I have to press enter or F5 for the page to load.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome, to no avail. I've even reset Windows, to no avail.

That's all this PC is for, there's nothing on it except Chrome.

Maybe Chrome won't load because there aren't enough resources available at startup (even if there is nothing on this computer...it's an old one and windows is "greedy")

How can I automatically refresh every 3 minutes?